# Cannot convert value of type ‚[[XXX]]‘ to expected argument type ‚[[XXX]]‘

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I implemented a custom class

```
class DisplayItem: NSObject {
…
}
```

that works correctly in my app.
It uses the function `findDisplayItemTableDifferences1` that determines differences between two 2-dim arrays. The 1st dimension are the sections of a `tableView`, the 2nd are the rows of a section. This 2nd row consists of elements of type `DisplayItem`:

```
func findDisplayItemTableDifferences1(oldTable: [[DisplayItem]], 
        newTable: [[DisplayItem]]) -> (deletions: [IndexPath], insertions: [IndexPath], movements: [(from: IndexPath, to: IndexPath)], updates: [IndexPath]) {
        …
}
```

To test the app, I wrote the 1st steps of a unit test:

```
func test_cellOperations() {
    // Given
    let shoppingItem1 = ShoppingItem.init(name: "Item1")
    let displayItem1 = DisplayItem.init(shoppingItem: shoppingItem1)
    let oldTable: [[DisplayItem]] = [[displayItem1]]
    var differences: (deletions: [IndexPath], insertions: [IndexPath], movements: [(from: IndexPath, to: IndexPath)], updates: [IndexPath])

    // When
    differences = ItemsViewModel.shared.findDisplayItemTableDifferences1(oldTable: oldTable, newTable: [[]])
}
```

This function does not compile. It creates at the line `differences =`, specifically at the argument `oldTable: oldTable`, the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[DisplayItem]]' to expected argument type '[[DisplayItem]]'
```

I assume this is an iOS a compiler error, at least the error message is very strange.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Try `[[DisplayItem]]()` as the newTable value. Sometimes the compiler needs a little inference help.

Comment: @ Warren Burton: Sorry, I was not clear about the error, which was raised at the argument `oldTable: oldTable`. I will edit my question

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, a [mcve] would be helpful.